# Failed to execute goal org.wso2.maven:mi-container-config-mapper:5.2.18:config-mapper-parser in wso2 docker image

Tags: docker, wso2

this is came from yesterday onwards, when i run the maven for docker project i am getting

Failed to execute goal org.wso2.maven:mi-container-config-mapper:5.2.35:config-mapper-parser (config-mapper-parser) on project ESBDockerExporter: Exception while parsing the deployment.toml file

this is the plug-in i added in docker pom.xml

Comment: <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>mi-container-config-mapper</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.18</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>config-mapper-parser</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>config-mapper-parser</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <miVersion>1.1.0</miVersion>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration/>
      </plugin>

Answer (score 0):

There is a known [issue](https://github.com/wso2/maven-tools/issues/78) that happening due to the new HTTPS template URL. So with the new URL HTTPS config, the older "mi-container-config-mapper" plugin has some issues.

So in order to correct this update the version in the k8s project pom file as below.

```
<artifactId>mi-container-config-mapper</artifactId>
<version>5.2.35</version>
```